# How to obtain the snowflake ID from Discord username?

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a form on my website for users to get notified by DM in discord for product updates. Here is just the relevant discord function:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = await client.fetch_user("DISCORD ID")
    await user.send("Example Update")


client.run("TOKEN GOES HERE")
```

This works if I provide the discord ID, but it would be much easier for my clients to copy and paste their username.

How do I get the snowflake ID via the discord API when the client enters their discord username?

I've searched posts here and I can only find solutions for the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find a user by his tag is if your bot and that person have a mutual connection (in a server and etc), the reversed way is the best working option as for now.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user

Another way to implement, is having a login with discord which will provide you anything you'll ever need.